# Find filepath that spawned process

Tags: process-management

I am using a Debian 9.13. Trough `ps -aux | grep NaughtyProcessName` i can find information about a given process that interests me in the format:

```
user.name [ID] [CPU USAGE] [%MEM] VSZ RSS TTY STAT START TIME COMMAND
```

Where command shows something like:

```
path/to/interpreter ./file_name.cmd
```

So i suppose some user was inside a mysterious directory which had `file_name.cmd` inside it and spawned a process by doing `./file_name.cmd`. The process uses the interpreter found in `path/to/interpreter`.

I want to know in which directory this file is. The only thing i know that i could try is

```
cd /
find -iname file_name.cmd
```

But that takes time and could find duplicates. Is there anything better and more straight to the point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a process id `<pid>`, then `/proc/<pid>/cwd` is a symlink to the working directory for that process. That is, if I run `python ./example.py` from `~/tmp/python`, in `ps` I will see:

```
$ ps -f -p 118054
UID          PID    PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
lars      118054    6793  0 09:16 pts/1    00:00:00 python ./example.py
```

And in `/proc/118054/cwd`, I see:

```
$ ls -l /proc/118054/cwd
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 lars lars 0 Aug 31 09:16 /proc/118054/cwd -> /home/lars/tmp/python
```

So you can use that information to infer that `./example.py` refers to `/home/lars/tmp/python/example.py`.

---

Note, however, that you cannot trust the information you see in the output of `ps`. Consider this simple C program:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv[]) {
    pid_t pid = getpid();
    printf("pid %d\n", pid);

    memset(argv[0], ' ', strlen(argv[0]));
    strcpy(argv[0], "ls");
    sleep(600);
    return 0;
}
```

If we run this:

```
$ ./example
pid 119217
```

And then look at `ps`:

```
$ ps -f -p 119217
UID          PID    PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
lars      119217    6793  0 09:25 pts/1    00:00:00 ls
```

It looks like we're running something completely innocuous.

Comment: Thanks! It worked for me and i believe it will work for most cases that i need.